# Place Cookie to prevent re-visiting site

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I have a contest site, I want it to prevent people going on it when they have submitted the form on the page. Is this possibe?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible to prevent people who don't care to cheat from returning, but impossible to prevent cheating by people who are willing to try trivial workarounds like clearing their cookies.

Comment: If the contest site requires registration, you can simply store a flag in the backend DB when a user submits their entry and then prevent the page from loading based on the presence of that flag.

Comment: Hi Psychmaster,

How would I store a flag and prevent the page from loading based on the flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build system where users are required to enter their email address, and enter a verification code which is sent to them. But they would only be able to enter this verification code once. Therefore, the only way of cheating would be to use two separate email addresses (and they would have to have access to both).

Cookies would not be the best option for this as anyone could clear their cookies.

Comment: Hi Daniel, how would I achieve this?

Comment: @user3582132 - he just told you

Comment: @user3582132 I would go about this in PHP. Have a email form, check if the email already exists in the database. If it does, don't allow entry. If it doesn't, add it to the database along with a random generated number. (`rand()`). Then use PHP email to sent an email to this address along with the verification code. Require the user to enter the code, and check if it matches up with the one stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily possible to **stop** users requesting a page, however you can either redirect them to another page or show some kind of error message to them, to tell them that  they can't resubmit.

Presuming you have some kind of user registration in place already (and are tying competition entries to those users with an ID) then all you would have to do is check for the existence of a competition entry in the database and then, if one is found, either force a redirect (likely in `<script>` tags) or replace the rendering of the page with the notice that you can't resubmit.